# Slightly rotating a div at the edge of the window without horizontal scrollbar appearing

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation, display

At the top of a page, I created four boxes/tiles which slightly rotate on hover (5 degree rotation). The boxes are positioned and sized via `flexbox` to span the entire width of the window. When hovering over the rightmost box, its bottom right corner moves out of the window on the right, causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear.

I would like to avoid the scrollbar from appearing. I tried doing so by setting `display: none` for the `<div>` containing the boxes, but this interferes with showing the rotation of the boxes in general as it cuts them off at the div's border when they rotate. I would like to keep the effect of the boxes rotating fully visible and avoid the horizontal scrollbar at the same time.

Here's my `html` and `css` as well as a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4kavrzL/) of the page (please note that the horizontal scrollbar does not always appear in the jsfiddle, depending on the size of the window in which the code is running):

```css
.banner {
  margin: 0px;

  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 1.2;
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
}

.rotate-right {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-left {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-right:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.rotate-left:hover {
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="top" id="top">
  <div>
    <div class="flex row banner">
      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          1
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          2
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          3
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          4
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden` on the div containing the boxes?

Comment: You tried to set html, body { overflow: hidden; } ? Or .top { overflow: hidden; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow-x: hidden` for your `body`. Demo:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

* {
  font-size: 6vw;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
}

.rotate-right {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-left {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-right:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.rotate-left:hover {
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="top" id="top">
  <div>
    <div class="flex row banner">
      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          1
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          2
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          3
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          4
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this command inside your class name if it is span let say then use like this

//for chrome

.span {

```
      &::-webkit-scrollbar{
            display: none;
        }
```

}

//for firefox

.span{

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

}